# Datepicker Field in Angular horizontal form misaligned

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a horizontal form in Angular using Bootstrap. I have one date field that is just slightly misaligned. Here is the code to the bootstrap sectioning I've worked out.

```
 <div class="form-group">

                    <div class="col-md-offset-6">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Ismessedup Date:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                              <p class="input-group">...
```

Here is the fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/c2bv2e6g/
You have to extend the screen to a wide view to see what I'm talking about.

Right now the left edge of the label is matched up (though it's not doing it in the fiddle properly, not sure why), but the Input Field of the IsMessedUp datepicker is a few millimeters to the right compared to the input fields above it. This is what I want to fix.

I have been able to line up both the label and the datepicker, the way I like, but then the datepicker is squished so you can no longer see the entire date. I want to keep them lined up but extend the length of the datepicker input field. I do this by changing the code here:

```
                    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                        <label class="col-md-6 control-label">Ismessedup Date: </label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <p class="input-group">..
```

Ultimately I want the field to be large enough to see the date as well as lining up with the field above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bootstrap grid is percentage based. So when you over-nest everything the way you have it is pretty much impossible to line things up, because each column is calculating it's % width off a different sized parent. You want to simplify and think about the grid you actually want...

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/c2bv2e6g/3/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Panel</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div ng-controller="CtrlController">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="firstthing" class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 control-label">First Thing</label>
                  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="firstthing" placeholder="">
                  </div>

                  <label for="Second Thing" class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-2"></label>
                  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="secondthing"
                           placeholder="Second Thing"
                           readonly>
                  </div>


                  <label for="thirdthing" class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 control-label">Third Thing</label>
                  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="thirdthing" placeholder="">
                  </div>

                  <label for="fourththing" class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="fourththing"
                           placeholder="fourththing"
                           readonly>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="fifththing" class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 control-label">Fifth Thing</label>
                  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="fifththing" placeholder="">
                  </div>
                  <label class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 control-label">Fifth thing </label>
                  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
                    <p class="input-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
                             ng-model="firstdt"
                             is-open="first.opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate"
                             datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                             ng-required="true" close-text="Close"/>
                      <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default input-sm" ng-click="open1()"><i
                                                                                                     class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                      </span>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <label for="Sixth Thing" class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 control-label">Sixth Thing</label>
                  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="sixththing" placeholder="">
                  </div>

                  <label for="sevenththing" class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="sevenththing"
                           placeholder="sevenththing"
                           readonly>
                  </div>
                </div>



                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-6 col-sm-2 control-label">Somethings Date:</label>
                  <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-10">
                    <p class="input-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"
                             uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
                             ng-model="somethingdt"
                             is-open="somethingdt.opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate"
                             datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                             ng-required="true" close-text="Close"/>
                      <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default input-sm" ng-click="open3()"><i
                                                                                                     class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                      </span>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div> <!-- div panel-body -->
    </div> <!-- div panel-heading -->
</div> <!-- div panel -->
```

Comment: I tried using your method and taking everything out of the nested <div>s but it's still offset http://jsfiddle.net/k0c0e68n/

Comment: Did you look at my fiddle? It's working in the fiddle. You also had just that one inside of a col-12 inside of an offset-6 so that row was structured different from the others. Look at the fiddle. I fixed a few extra things and it's lined up. http://i.imgur.com/Mwf6oGN.png

Comment: Ah hah! I had looked at your fiddle and made most of the changes but I did miss one thing, and now it works. Thank you!